# Update ListView previous clicked item

Tags: android, android-listview

I have ListView which is customized to have a EditText box and a Button in it. The ListView displays text boxes as `visible` but the button as `invisible`. When the user clicks on an item in the ListView, the Button's made visible. I have written the following code for the ListView:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {    
    view.findViewById(R.id.button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

The above code functions in the case when the first item's Button and the second item's Button are visible.

**My problem:**
When the next item in the ListView is clicked, the Button from the previous item should become invisible as the current item's Button becomes visible. So how do I update the view of the previous item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store the previous row in a class variable:

```
View previous;
...

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {    
    if(previous != null)
        previous.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    // Set the current button to visible while saving it for the next click 
    previous = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    previous.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

---

**Addition from comments**

You're right. The adapter's view recycling is affecting the other rows so let's extend whatever adapter you are using and override its `getView()` method:

```
public int selectedRow = -1;
...

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    // Here, either use findViewById() (slower) or the ViewHolder method (faster) to load the button:
    // Button button = ...

    if(position == selectedRow) 
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    else
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    return view;
}
```

And in your `onItemClick()` method add a line like this:

```
adapter.selectedRow = position;
```

Comment: The above code is wrking. Thanx. But the size of the layout increases. How do I bring it to the original size?

Comment: Done! Instead of View.INVISIBLE, I had converted into View.GONE.

Comment: There is a problem. As I scroll down, the button is visible in an item below which is second last. I think that the view is getting recycled. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Attach a listener on the button instead of the listview itself. You could do it in the getview() method.